# Replace Two/Three words with one anchor tag using Php

Tags: php, laravel, string, preg-replace, str-replace

I have:

```
<p>
#mango #orange Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
</p>
```

I want to replace #values, that is: #mango, #orange with *single*:

```
<a href="#">Link</a>
```

So my expected:

```
<p>
<a href="#">Link</a>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
</p>
```

I tried:

```
<?php 
if( $sentence != '' ) {
    $sentence=preg_replace("/#([A-Za-z0-9\_\-\.]*)/", "<a href='#'>Link</a>", $sentence);
    }
?>
```

But it replaces both #mango and #orange with two anchor tags: **Link** and **Link** instead I want to replace all # words with one anchor tag.

Comment: This is not a free write-my-code-for-me service. What have you tried? Where **exactly** are you stuck at? Its also not clear what you want. You want a regex or what are you searching for?

Comment: You are probably being downvoted because you didn't provide any code to show what you tried, which makes this appear to be a "please write code for free for me" type of question.

Comment: Thankyou! @ChrisHaas Updated with what I tried.

Comment: Thanks @RiyaSingh. Can you further tell us what the results of that are and why they don't match your expectations?

Comment: Could the text ever be `#mango Lorem #orange`? Or are the words that start with `#` always at the front?

Comment: @ChrisHaas #mango and #orange are always at the front. I have my all posts descriptions with such format, that is, two hash tags words at the begininng, and now i decided to replace those with two hash words with single link. (I do not want to update my database description column for some reason.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3639136/367456

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this regex is what you are looking for:

```php
$sentence = <<<TAG
<p>
#mango #orange Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
</p>
TAG;

$sentence = preg_replace("/(#([\w\-.]*)+ )+/", "<a href='#'>Link</a> ", $sentence);

echo $sentence;
```

The one major change is that I'm also looking for a space afterwards, so it needs to be added back into the replacement portion.

Demo here: https://3v4l.org/qKEAq